# General & open-ended: Guidelines to develop process-flow oriented web experience (using inheritance)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, workflow, frontend

This is a general question, so perhaps it makes sense to move it elsewhere in stack-exchange (?)

I am hoping to get some general opinions (guidelines?) on the best way to design a web experience that is **heavily** process oriented. Meaning the customer will go through multiple screens and based on their selections will see the next screen, effectively going through a flow etc, etc.

There will be several main baseline flows and multiple variances of them depending on how customers choose to interact with each screen/view. This fact can lead the design to follow an inheritance model.

Are there any front-end, java-script-based tools and frameworks well suited for this? Do you see inheritance playing a major role in this case? If so, how ?

Many thanks for any comments